# Is it acceptable to ask for the rules or instructions to an obscure board game?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I've read the help center and seen nothing about not asking for rules, and I've done several searches here on Meta for the same information. Since I can't find a definitive answer, I prefer to check before I ask the question.

Recently, I found a board game I'd never heard of in a rummage sale: "Deer Hunters Challenge" from Mills Game CO. I bought it and brought it home, and while it appears to have all the pieces, there are no instructions with the game.

I've used every combination of search terms I can think of, and browsed several "board game rules" sites and this game just does not come up. It seems to be a pretty rare and obscure game.

Would it be on-topic to ask for the rules/instructions to this game on this site?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is perfectly acceptable as finding the rules for a board game is on topic even if it is an obscure one. The fact that you have done some searching on your own is also good as it shows you are not just expecting others to find the answer for you.

I would go and post your question and best of luck on finding the rules.